# Error "<NodeName> was not expected" when creating XML using XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on an app an i'm saving the data in an XML format but i'm having issues with getting the format correct.

the output looks like this

```
 <GasInfoEntries>
   <Gallons>123</Gallons>
   <Price>456</Price>
 </GasInfoEntries><GasInfoEntries>
   <Gallons>123</Gallons>
   <Price>456</Price>
 </GasInfoEntries>
```

im using this to write it

```
List<GasInfoEntries> data = new List<GasInfoEntries>();

                        data.Add(new GasInfoEntries() { Gallons = TxtBoxGas.Text, Price = TxtBoxPrice.Text });
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("GasInfoEntries");

                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Gallons", "");
                        xmlWriter.WriteString(TxtBoxGas.Text);
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();


                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Price", "");
                        xmlWriter.WriteString(TxtBoxPrice.Text);
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

                        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                        xmlWriter.Flush();
                        //do i need?
                        xmlWriter.Close();
```

i'm getting this error

```
- $exception
{System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <GasInfoEntries xmlns=''> was not expected.
    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read3_ArrayOfGasInfoEntries()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
    at LP_Buddy.MainPage.btnShow_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)}
System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the root XML element which is required in XML document. Just add it like this:

```
<GasRoot>
    <GasInfoEntries>
      <Gallons>123</Gallons>
      <Price>456</Price>
    </GasInfoEntries>
    <GasInfoEntries>
      <Gallons>123</Gallons>
      <Price>456</Price>
    </GasInfoEntries>
</GasRoot>
```

Comment: do i have to declare it in the code behind? like xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("GasRoot"); thanks

Comment: well having second thoughts...still having some issues.will it be possible to add and remove records from an xml file on the phone or should i switch to a database?

Comment: @user2712080 certainly, you have to define it explicitly as any other element. Removing element from XML is certainly possible, but that would require rewriting a whole file (if you plan to use XmlWriter). If you plan to update/change data in the file, then database if certainly a better solution.

Comment: Thanks going to go with database... at least I learned to write an xml file!